# What sort of tape adheres best to painted drywall?

Tags: paint, tape

I have a painted drywall ceiling and want to stick some low-density stuff onto it (things like rope, plastic, maybe some strips of wood). The stuff I stick on would not have a footprint that goes beyond the tape surface, but it might extend a few centimeters down into the room. I want some tape that would stay stuck for a long time with minimal shifting. I'm thinking of an indoor heated room in the US Midwest. Not sure what kind of paint/drywall.

Comment: Need more specifics: Does the tape need to be removal without damage to the paint? How long do you want the tape/taped item to stay up? How heavy is the item being taped up?

Comment: Thanks! I will add detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm... this is odd. Usually the question is "what kind of tape *comes off* of drywall"! Darn near anything will stick to painted drywall far better than you'd want it to.

- Masking tape will likely hold reasonably well, but may not support much weight and will dry out and fall off after a couple of years.
- **Duck** tape (the generic cloth-backed stuff, not specifically the brand name) will hold a reasonable amount of weight and will last for years.
- **Duct** tape (the aluminum/foil backed stuff specifically designed for duct work) probably won't hold as well as it does to to galvanized steel ducts
- Gaffer's tape will hold about as well as duck tape and will, generally, come off cleanly, but will leave marks after a couple of years. (Ask me how I know)
- Electrical tape probably won't hold all that well or support all that much weight.
- Double-sided carpet tape will probably do the job quite nicely especially if the wall is pretty smooth.
- Double-sided foam-backed tape may hold pretty well, especially if either the surface of the wall or item to be mounted is rough/textured.

Comment: Cool thanks! Haha, I did not realize how weird my question was, but now that you put it that way....I will mark this as the answer tomorrow.

Comment: no worries, @capet. Keep an eye open for other answers - there are lots of smart people 'round here with lots of different experiences. Someone may be able to give you something more concrete than "best guesses and logical thinking".

Comment: “Duck” tape is actually just a brand of cloth-backed duct tape, no? It was originally intended to seal ducts, but it cracks and crumbles very quickly with the repeated heat cycling of ductwork and therefore is now recommended for anything but ducts—hence the switch to foil-backed duct tape for this purpose.

Comment: I vote for Double-sided foam-backed tape, given the shape of the objects you mention, as well as the likely texture of the ceiling. Moreover, the contact area is largest and mechanical tear-off stresses are least if the tape is fully in contact with the ceiling as opposed to having it wrapped half-around, and bracing the object

Comment: Tuck tape has the highest adhesion per square cm but too much and it will pull off the paint and the next layer if removed.  Carpet tape will sag and fall off in hours or days. 1-sided red.  https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/tuck-tape-construction-grade-sheathing-tape-0676000p.html

Comment: Yes, @statueuphemism, that's why I specified the differences between "duck" tape and "duct" tape, listing them individually and noted that I was referring to "duck tape" in the generic sense, not the brand name.

Comment: @FreeMan More confusing to mix in a brand name as a generic description than “cloth-backed duct tape” and “foil-backed duct tape” if you ask me. To each their own.

Comment: And, since we're picking nits, @statueuphemism, most people pronounce both of them "duck" tape without having the slightest clue that it's a trademarked name brand or that it's _wrong_ when referring to the foil-backed backed stuff designed for HVAC use. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan Sorry to nitpick, only reason I mentioned it is because I know an otherwise pretty smart guy who actually read the label on Duck tape. saw the word “Duct”, and tried to seal all of his ductwork with it. If I can save one more person that much misguided effort with a quick comment to emphasize the difference, I wanted to do so.

Comment: Fair enough, @statueuphemism, and now to stop before we get yelled at for chatting in the comments. :)